# Optimize a query with expression

Tags: sql, mysql-8.0

I have a query that runs about 1.40 seconds on average.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - votes.time) as time, `votes`.`time` as `timestamp`, `users`.`avatar`, `location`.`country_code`, `users`.`full_name`, `contests`.`contest_id`, `contestants`.`contestant_name`, `contestants`.`extSrcVideo`, `contestants`.`contestant_id`, `contests`.`contest_cxid`, `contestants`.`contestant_img`, `contestants`.`youtubeVideoId`, `contests`.`contest_slug`, `contests`.`contest_name`, `votes`.`vote_number` as `qty`
FROM `contest_assoc`
JOIN `contestants` ON `contestants`.`contestant_id` = `contest_assoc`.`contestant_id`
JOIN `contests` ON `contests`.`contest_id` = `contest_assoc`.`contest_id`
JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`assoc_id` = `contest_assoc`.`contest_assoc_id`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`ID` = `votes`.`user_id`
JOIN `location` ON `location`.`user_id` = `users`.`ID`
GROUP BY `votes`.`user_id`
ORDER BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - votes.time) ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                     | rows   | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | votes         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    | 106312 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contest_assoc | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | onlyWinners.votes.assoc_id              |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contests      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | onlyWinners.contest_assoc.contest_id    |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contestants   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | onlyWinners.contest_assoc.contestant_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | onlyWinners.votes.user_id               |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | location      | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    | 135670 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

if I add index to location.user, the filtered goes up from 10 to 100, but the executetion time goes up to 1.85 seconds.

I've tried to apply some indexing, but I failed, probably I've missed something here.

I think the challenge lies in the expression `(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - votes.time)`, but I might be wrong.

I want to make it 3-4 times faster, is this possible?

Comment: Often issues of slowness is about errors of joins caused by cardinality not respected. But have you try the sub queries ?

Comment: I write about sub queries because this `group by` with this difference of time and many columns is strange for me.

Comment: I've tried the sub queries. But, the time goes up to 1.6 seconds. But, I may do it wrong when creating the sub query. Could you please elaborate on how to write the sub query?

Comment: What about using `Sql Views` or `mixed indexes`?

Comment: I think that SQL Views will produce the same problem as it's a query stored in a table. I've tried the composite indexes, but no luck, but I might do it wrong though.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the ORDER BY? However, I don’t think your query is improvable so you would have to look at your environment if you wanted to speed it up

Comment: @NickW, if I remove the ORDER BY, it's executed in 1.36 seconds, it looks like it doesn't affect much.

Comment: You just gave me an idea @NickW. I tried to remove the GROUP BY and it finally executes in 0.01 sec! I think the problem here is the GROUP BY.

Comment: hmm... But if I remove the GROUP BY and then use the ORDER BY, it executes in 1.12 seconds.

Comment: It's really hard to tell from your sample query want you want, because you are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has no WHERE filters, but only an ORDER BY ... LIMIT filter. And it has a puzzling GROUP BY clause that isn't matched by the SELECT clause.

So your best path to a fast query plan is to use an index to access the `votes` table.

1. Get rid of the GROUP BY clause.
2. Change the ORDER BY clause to `ORDER BY votes.time DESC`. This will give you the same result as your sample query, but uses a direct column reference rather than an expression reference.
3. Put this index on your `votes` table.

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX time ON votes(time DESC);
   ```

This will let that index be used to find the ten most recent rows in that table, which should cut down on the server workload.

Comment: I like your idea! I've done no 2 and 3, but I haven't thought about no 1. I think it should still return the results I want. Many thanks!